# text loaded from localStorage goes away on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

There is a bootstrap modal which takes 3 inputs: Name,image, and description. I have figured out how to save everything to local storage and load the form inputs to my webpage, however, the text elements disappear on refresh so I'm hoping I can get tips regarding this.

```
apply.onclick = function () {                       //function executed when form submitted
    var name = document.getElementById("name2").value;      //save name to a var
    var description = document.getElementById("description2").value;
    localStorage.setItem("name", name);                    //set name to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem("description", description);

    updateProduct(); //function to load into divs from local storage
}

function updateProduct(){
    $("#title2").html(localStorage.name);
    $("#desc2").html(localStorage.description); //load name&desciption into divs
}
```

This successfully sets the name and description in their respective divs, but  once the page refreshes the text is erased and reset to whatever it was before "apply" was clicked. Is there a different method for saving & loading from local storage I should be using?

Comment: Show us your full code...maybe setting a flag can do the trick...I think that you are assigning a value to localStorage in another part of your code....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to invoke the `updateProduct` function when your page loads. Currently you're only invoking it in the onclick handler from what you've shown here.

You can this by applying the following technique:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (document.readyState == "interactive") {
        initApplication();
    }
}
```

Anything that you want to be applied during application initialization should be in your `initApplication` function that you define.

You can read about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/readystatechange) on MDN.

Comment: How do you think I should do this? I tried using the JQuery document.ready function and $(window).on('load', function(){ but both of these resulted in other inputs on the page not responding (buttons don't work and such)

Comment: but will not have any data if no click has ever occured

Comment: @charlietfl I believe it has default settings that are applied if nothing has ever been stored in localStorage

Comment: @MikeHawk I will update my answer to show you how to do this

Comment: @charlietfl he implicitly states that it has defaults; "but once the page refreshes the text is erased and reset to whatever it was before "apply" was clicked". Note the "whatever it was __before__" part.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect now